# How to set Style to WPFToolkit DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF, am developing using C# and .NET3.5. I have a WPFToolkit's DataGrid added to my window. I am not able to figure out how to set Style to the Column Header and Rows? Rows are added dynamically.

```
        <my:datagrid name="myGrid" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit" itemssource="{Binding }" autogeneratecolumns="False">
                 SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                 ColumnHeaderHeight="42" Background="#FFF7F7F7" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                 HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFEAEAEA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFEAEAEA" 
                 HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeaderWidth="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ClipboardCopyMode="None" MinRowHeight="28" 
                 Rowremoved="#FFF7F7F7" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" RowHeight="28" 
                 DataContextChanged="serverGrid_DataContextChanged">
        <my:datagrid.columns>
            <my:datagridtextcolumn header="Enabled" width="120" binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <my:datagridtextcolumn header="Enabled" width="70" binding="{Binding Path=Country}" />
            <my:datagridtextcolumn header="Enabled" width="100" binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
        </my:datagrid.columns>

    </my:datagrid>
```

In the Resources have added code for Style :

```
    <!-- DataGridColumnHeader-->
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <setter property="Background" value="#9DCFD0" />
        <setter property="FontFamily" value="Arial Rounded MT" />
        <setter property="FontSize" value="14" />
        <setter property="FontWeight" value="Bold" />
        <setter property="Foreground" value="#00545B" />
        <setter property="VerticalContentAlignment" value="Center" />
        <setter property="HorizontalContentAlignment" value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

In TargetType of Style, am not able to set as `my:DataGridColumnHeader` or just `DataGridColumnHeader`. It says "... not found". In `my:DataGridTextColumn` I guess `HeaderStyle` is the property to set the style. But am able to define Style for the same.

Also how to set style for Rows added dynamically? Where am I going wrong?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

First is the namespace to header:

```
xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
```

then this is style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#654b24"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="bold"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#f7f3de" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#Fcfcfc" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: with this on run time, while Show(), I get the following error in Debug " 'DataGridColumnHeader' TargetType does not match type of element 'DataGridCell'.". Without Debug, it just exits and doesn't show anything.

Comment: Have set the datagrid's `CellStyle` to `DataGridColumnHeaderStyle`? They are clearly two different things.

Comment: But the TargetType i.e. DataGridColumnHeader is not accessible. I have access to only my: DataGrid, DataGridCell, DataGridcellsPanel, DataGridHeaderBorder and DataRow in respect to DataGrid - tried thru xaml by typtin "<my:".

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [these tutorials](http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/), there are four in total and cover most aspects of `DataGrid` styling.

The linked article is the second in the series and covers most of the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Probable reason why you dont see `my:DataGridColumnHeader` is because its in the `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives` namespace. Does `my` represent this namespace as well?

Use

```
 xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

instead.

**EDIT**

Then refer the DataGridColumnHeader as

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader}">
     ....
 </Style>
```

Remember to NOT give any Key to it so that would apply to all headers.

Comment: "my" was set in my DataGrid initialization : <my:datagrid name="myGrid" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit" itemssource="{Binding }".  I removed it from there and added on top in Windows tag :     xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit" 
    Title="Window2" .

Comment: I have access to only my: DataGrid, DataGridCell, DataGridcellsPanel, DataGridHeaderBorder and DataRow in respect to DataGrid. I tried setting the TargetType to DataCell, then al rows are given that style and headers are given only when mouseover. I want different styles for Col Headers & Rows.